# Array element being seemingly ignored?

Tags: php

I'm writing a basic function in php, but something very weird is happening. $ary has a value with the key "Keyword", and when I var_dump($ary) it shows that the keyword value is present. But, when I target it with $ary['Keyword'], it returns null. For example, take a look at the code below.

```
        echo var_dump($ary);
        echo var_dump($ary['Keyword']) . "<br><br><br>";
```

It will output

```
myinfopleasedontsteal/php:354:
array (size=2)
  'Keyword' => string 'Acceptance' (length=10)
  '' => string '' (length=0)
myinfopleasedontsteal/php:355:null
```

Why is $ary['Keyword'] returning null instead of the string?
It may be important to mention that $ary is an element of a list that is formed from a csv document, if it matters.

edit: var_dump(array_keys($ary)) prints this

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Keyword' (length=10)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
```

Here's the code that converts the CSV to an array

```
function LOAD_CSV2ARRAY($filename='') // Converts a CSV to an associated 2d array
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {

            if(!$header)
            {
               $header = $row; // tried replacing this with the line commented out below
                // $header = array_map('trim',$row);
            }
            else
            {
                if(count($header)!=count($row)){ continue; }
                // $header = array_map('trim',$header); tried adding this
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: `var_dump(array_keys($ary));`

Comment: Just tried that, added an edit to the bottom of the post showing what it prints

Comment: See? `Keyword` has length 10.

Comment: That's funky, what could be causing that? The original document it's extracted from is a CSV created through microsoft excel, if that helps

Comment: Unprintable characters. Apply `trim`

Comment: I tried applying trim to the header in function I was using to convert the CSV into an array, which I yoinked off of stack overflow years ago so I'm not familiar with it and couldn't get it working  @u_mulder

Comment: Editted to show where I added/replaced code to try and apply trim

Comment: If you got vim editor you can use `:set list ` to show if there isn't any unprintable characters. You can check also by writing `$ary = array_map("utf8_encode", $ary);` then trying to acces ```['Keyword']```

Comment: Applying `trim` should work, unless you have some symbols that `trim` doesn't remove by default.

Comment: array_map(utf8_encode) didn't work, since I think that targets the array elements, not the key values. I changed the CSV code to apply that to the headers, now it's printing a bunch of different keys: `ï»¿Keyword` and `Ã¯Â»Â¿Keyword`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was causing the problem. I was exporting the excel spreadsheet as a UTF8 encoded CSV. If I export it as a plain CSV, the key doesn't include any unprintable characters